# To pass one actions output to another action in oozie workflow

Tags: oozie

I have a requirement like i need to pass an actions output(like action_name,success/failed) to another action in a oozie workflow. Kindly pass some information how to schedule the actions ? This is first time I am working on oozie and looking for help

Comment: Show us the code you tried

Comment: <workflow-app name="Test_Process" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4"><global>
<job-xml>/XXX/XXX/XXXX/hive-config.xml</job-xml>
 </global><start to="Test_Process"/><action name="Test_Process"><shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
<job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker><name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
<exec>XXXX.sh</exec><argument>${XXXXXXXXXXX}</argument><argument>${wf:appPath()}</argument><argument>${wf:name()}</argument>
<file>XXXX.sh#XXXX.sh</file>
<file>${XXXXXXXXXXX}#${XXXXXXXXXXX}</file><capture-output/></shell><ok to="end"/><error to="kill"/>
</action><end name="end"/></workflow-app>

Comment: Something I have tried like this..

Comment: The action name is not an output; it's the *key* to get the actual output - provided that you are retrieving it from the **same workflow**. And "success/failed" is not an output in the sense of `<capture_output/>`, see https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2.3_Workflow_EL_Functions and especially `wf:transition(String node)`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply.I need to pass the action name, status  as input to a shell script  which will inturn right into a text file.